# Aliasing in STL string

Tags: c++, stl

I've found this code in std::basic_string class

```
union _Bxty
    {   // storage for small buffer or pointer to larger one
    _Elem _Buf[_BUF_SIZE];
    _Elem *_Ptr;
    char _Alias[_BUF_SIZE]; // to permit aliasing
    } _Bx;
```

And I can't understand how _Alias permits actual aliasing. Search gives nothing. I'm curious about if this member can be just removed without any problems.

Comment: I have no idea what it actually does, but removing it wouldn't actually matter in terms of memory usage. for `std::string`, `_Elem` is `char`, so `_Elem _Buf[_BUF_SIZE]` has essentially the same size as `char _Alias[_BUF_SIZE]`, so the union of the two types doesn't require any extra space. You'll have to see how it's used in the rest of the code to know what it actually does.

Comment: You aren't seriously proposing to edit the MSVC++ headers to remove members from `std::string`? Because that is a seriously bad idea.

Comment: Of course I wouldn't think about changing the MSVC header. I wondered about the actual idea of using this type of protection.

Answer (score 2):

This code is part of the implementation, which means it may rely on very dirty tricks. The basic idea is that depending on string size, either `_Buf` or `_Ptr` is valid. But here's the problem: which of the two is active? You can't look at the content of either to figure it out, because you may violate the only-read-active rule (which is a specific case of aliasing).

However, regardless of which of the two members is active, you can access `_Alias`. In particular, you can `memcpy` copy it such that you either memcpy the pointer or memcpy the characters, without knowing what you memcpy'ed.

What's dirty is the lack of `*sizeof(_Elem)` in the size of `_Alias[]`. I'll bet that there is an out-of-bounds access to `_Alias` for `std::wstring`. It's just not a hard error on MSVC++, and inside `std::wstring` Undefined behavior doesn't count.

Comment: Let's say I've two strings
`string t1("Hello, this is test");`
`string t2("Hello");`
In the first case data in `_Bx` will be stored as
`{
_Buf=0x009afb90 "pл"
_Ptr=0x00eb1a70 "Hello, this is test"
_Alias=0x009afb90 "pл"
}`
and in the second case it will look like
`{
_Buf=0x009afb68 "Hello"
_Ptr=0x6c6c6548 <Bad Ptr>
_Alias=0x009afb68 "Hello"
}`
So if the `_Ptr` is inited both arrays have it's address in first four bytes and if the `_Ptr` is not inited - both arrays will have the actual string. So we can't use `_Alias` since it's mostly the same as using the `_Buf`. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: @Richer: Yes, `std::wstring`.